# How to get the exact copy of original Run task in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Does anybody know what the simplest way to register several run tasks that represent exact copy of original one with changed app’s arguments ? Or may be how to supply run task with an optional argument that would represent app’s arguments.
Basically, I want my build to contain some pre-defined options how to run an application and don’t want to declare new JavaExec that requires its manual configuring while I have already had ready-to-go run task supplied by default.

```
gradle run --args='--mode=middle'      ---> gradle run || gradle runDefault || gradle run default
gradle run --args='--mode=greed'       ---> gradle runGreed || gradle run greed
gradle run --args='--mode=lavish'      ---> gradle runLavish || gradle run lavish
```

As for now I came up only with the option that suggests implementing my own JavaExec_Custom task class with supplied arguments property. And it seems to be too complex and boilerplating as for my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create tasks that modify the configuration of the actual `run` task in a `doFirst` or `doLast` closure:

```
// Groovy-DSL

task runGreed {
    doFirst {
        run.args '--mode=greed'
    }
    finalizedBy run
}


// Kotlin-DSL

register("runGreed") {
    doFirst {
        run.get().args = listOf("--mode=greed")
    }
    finalizedBy(run)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property for the args

```
task run(type: JavaExec) {
   args property('run.args').split(' ')
   ...
}
```

Usage

> gradle run -Prun.args='foo bar baz'